# Append DataFrame to an Index Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I have lots of nests in my data. I have 6 time periods (but let's not worry about that), each time period has 19 quantiles, each quantile has a 51x51 covariance matrix (for all states and DC of USA). If represented as a dictionary, I would have:

```
my_data = {'time_pd_1' : {0.05 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.05), columns=states, index=states),
                         {0.10 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.10), columns=states, index=states),
                          ...
                         {0.90 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.90), columns=states, index=states),
                         {0.95 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.95), columns=states, index=states)},
           'time_pd_2' : {0.05 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.05), columns=states, index=states),
                         {0.10 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.10), columns=states, index=states),
                          ...
                         {0.90 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.90), columns=states, index=states),
                         {0.95 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.95), columns=states, index=states)},
            ...
           'time_pd_6' : {0.05 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.05), columns=states, index=states),
                         {0.10 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.10), columns=states, index=states),
                          ...
                         {0.90 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.90), columns=states, index=states),
                         {0.95 : pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_0.95), columns=states, index=states)}}
```

Easy enough, but the data is not created like this. I have two `for` loops that do the work:

```
for tpd in time_periods:
    for q in quantiles:
        tdf = pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_q), index=states, columns=states)
```

If I were to print `tdf` it looks like this:

```
ST              Alabama         Alaska          Arizona         ...     West Virginia   Wisconsin   Wyoming
ST                                                                                                             
Alabama         288.867628      50.000000       -100.062576     ...     37.719317       0           -75.000000
Alaska          50.000000       280.929272      -229.365427     ...     57.514555       0           -136.365512
Arizona         -100.062576     -229.365427     946.563177      ...     -113.805612     0           291.897723
...             ...             ...             ...             ...     ...             ...         ...
West Virginia   37.719317       57.514555       -113.805612     ...     342.195976      0           -214.243277
Wisconsin       0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        ...     0.000000        0           0.000000
Wyoming         -75.000000      -136.365512     291.897723      ...     -214.243277     0           684.146619
```

Now, what I want is this:

```
cov = {}
for tpd in time_periods:
    cov[tpd] = pd.DataFrame(index=[str(round(q,2)) for q in quantiles])
    for q in quantiles:
        tdf = pd.DataFrame(data=cov_var(data_for_q), index=states, columns=states)
        cov[tpd].loc[str(round(q,2)), :] = tdf
```

So if I print `cov[tpd]` it should look like:

```
        ST              Alabama         Alaska          Arizona         ...     West Virginia   Wisconsin   Wyoming
q       ST                                                                                                             
        Alabama         288.867628      50.000000       -100.062576     ...     37.719317       0           -75.000000
        Alaska          50.000000       280.929272      -229.365427     ...     57.514555       0           -136.365512
        Arizona         -100.062576     -229.365427     946.563177      ...     -113.805612     0           291.897723
0.05    ...             ...             ...             ...             ...     ...             ...         ...
        West Virginia   37.719317       57.514555       -113.805612     ...     342.195976      0           -214.243277
        Wisconsin       0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        ...     0.000000        0           0.000000
        Wyoming         -75.000000      -136.365512     291.897723      ...     -214.243277     0           684.146619
        Alabama         288.867628      50.000000       -100.062576     ...     37.719317       0           -75.000000
        Alaska          50.000000       280.929272      -229.365427     ...     57.514555       0           -136.365512
        Arizona         -100.062576     -229.365427     946.563177      ...     -113.805612     0           291.897723
0.10    ...             ...             ...             ...             ...     ...             ...         ...
        West Virginia   37.719317       57.514555       -113.805612     ...     342.195976      0           -214.243277
        Wisconsin       0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        ...     0.000000        0           0.000000
        Wyoming         -75.000000      -136.365512     291.897723      ...     -214.243277     0           684.146619
...     ...             ...             ...             ...             ...     ...             ...         ...
...     ...             ...             ...             ...             ...     ...             ...         ...
        Alabama         288.867628      50.000000       -100.062576     ...     37.719317       0           -75.000000
        Alaska          50.000000       280.929272      -229.365427     ...     57.514555       0           -136.365512
        Arizona         -100.062576     -229.365427     946.563177      ...     -113.805612     0           291.897723
0.90    ...             ...             ...             ...             ...     ...             ...         ...
        West Virginia   37.719317       57.514555       -113.805612     ...     342.195976      0           -214.243277
        Wisconsin       0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        ...     0.000000        0           0.000000
        Wyoming         -75.000000      -136.365512     291.897723      ...     -214.243277     0           684.146619
        Alabama         288.867628      50.000000       -100.062576     ...     37.719317       0           -75.000000
        Alaska          50.000000       280.929272      -229.365427     ...     57.514555       0           -136.365512
        Arizona         -100.062576     -229.365427     946.563177      ...     -113.805612     0           291.897723
0.95    ...             ...             ...             ...             ...     ...             ...         ...
        West Virginia   37.719317       57.514555       -113.805612     ...     342.195976      0           -214.243277
        Wisconsin       0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        ...     0.000000        0           0.000000
        Wyoming         -75.000000      -136.365512     291.897723      ...     -214.243277     0           684.146619
```

Having this final structure will make my life so much easier, that I am willing to buy a beer for the person who gets it. That apart, I have tried various things:

```
cov[tpd].loc[str(round(q,2)), :] = tdf # Raises ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
cov[tpd].loc[str(round(q,2)), :].append(tdf) # Almost gives me the frame I need, but removes the index level q, and inserts a column 0 with NaNs
cov[tpd].loc[str(round(q,2)), :].join(tdf, how='outer') # Raises AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
pd.merge(cov[tpd].loc[str(round(q,2)), :], tdf, how='outer') # Raises AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I understand all the error messages, and I also have a potential fix which involves pre-creating the DataFrame `cov[tpd]` the way I want it, then use indexing to insert the output from `cov_var()`. But that is a few extra lines of code to create the multiindex for `cov[tpd]` and then inserting the data. Does anyone know a better way?

---

Note: `cov_var()` is a simple covariance computing function that I wrote because my case is a little special, and I cannot use a built in function like `np.cov()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally gave in, and used the method I hinted at in the question above. It actually appears to be faster than the method I was so adamant at trying. All's good. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
cov = {}
ind_lev_1 = [str(round(q,2)) for q in quantiles]
ind_lev_2 = states
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ind_lev_1, ind_lev_2], names=['QUANTILE', 'STATE'])
columns = pd.Index(ind_lev_2, name='STATE')

for tpd in time_periods:
    cov[tpd] = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
    for q in quantiles:
        q = str(round(q,2))
        cov[tpd].loc[(q,), :] = cov_var(arr=data_for_q, means=pop_means_for_q)
```